# Associating matrix ${\sin t,\cos t}$ ex

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> In each of the following cases, let $D=\frac{d}{dt}$ be the derivative. We give a set of linearly independent functions $\mathscr{B}$. These generate a vector space $V$, and $D$ is a linear map from V into itself. Find the matrix associated with $D$ relative to the bases $\mathscr{B}$,$\mathscr{B}$.
>
> f) ${\sin t,\cos t}$

$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\sin t\\\cos t\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\cos t\\-\sin t\end{bmatrix}$

**Questions:**

**1)** Is the method I am using to answer this sort of question right?(I am self studying and my book has no solutions)

**2)** What are the functions and values of $a,b,c,d$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is your method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are working in the space $\{a\sin+b\cos\,|\,a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$, your linear map $D$ is the derivative and you want to find the matrix of this linear map with respect to the basis $\mathcal{B}=\{\sin,\cos\}$. Well, since $D(\sin)=\cos$ and since $D(\cos)=-\sin$, your matrix is $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, because $D$ maps the first vector of $\mathcal B$ into the second one and maps the second vector of $\mathcal B$ into the symmetric of the first one.